# Scala : how to keep only paths containing a full list of points

Tags: scala, path

I have a problem where I need to find all the paths that contains a list of stops, both the list of paths and the list of points given in parameter.

A path is a Vector of segment, a segment is two points ("From" point and "To" point).

So far, my function to find a list of path which include a list of given points is

```
def containsListOfStops(paths: List[Path], points: List[Point]): List[Path]={

if (paths.isEmpty) List()
(for {
    point <- points
    path <- containsIntermediateStop(paths,point)
  } yield path).distinct
```

containsIntermediateStop if a function which return a path containing a given point.

my problem is that it returns all the paths containing at least one of the points in the list, where I only want the paths containing every point.

Do you have any idea which could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain a bit more.

Comment: Sample inputs along with the expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: Also, put an `else` before `(for {...` otherwise you will get surprises.

Answer (score 0):

you are sending each all paths and a single point to the `containsIntermediateStop` function.
How about doing something like

```
def containsPoints(path: Path, points: List[Point]): Boolean = ??? //implement checking all points in path
```

than you can simply do something like (no need for the `for` loop)

```
paths.distinct.filter(path => containsPoints(path, points))
```

is that works for you ?